# latex to sympy conversion

Tags: python, latex

```
from sympy.parsing.latex import parse_latex
expr = parse_latex(r"\frac {1 + \sqrt {\a}} {\b}")
```

I am trying above code to convert latex expression to sympy expression format. Getting given error even after installation of antlr4. I am using python3 version.

```
ImportError: LaTeX parsing requires the antlr4 python package, provided by pip (antlr4-python2-runtime or antlr4-python3-runtime) or conda (antlr-python-runtime)
```

How to resolve this? Is there any dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `antlr4` but you also need a specific version.

At the time of writing this (02/2023), the `parse_latex` function of `sympy` is [implemented this way](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/26f7bdbe3f860e7b4492e102edec2d6b429b5aaf/sympy/parsing/latex/_parse_latex_antlr.py#L61):

```py
def parse_latex(sympy):
    antlr4 = import_module('antlr4')

    if None in [antlr4, MathErrorListener] or \
            version('antlr4-python3-runtime') != '4.10':
        raise ImportError("LaTeX parsing requires the antlr4 Python package,"
                          " provided by pip (antlr4-python3-runtime) or"
                          " conda (antlr-python-runtime), version 4.10")

    ...
```

Which explicitly check for the version number.
So you need to have the 4.10 version as also stated in the error message:

`pip install antlr4-python3-runtime==4.10`

(See also the runtime installation [instructions](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html#runtime-installation))

Then you can test it like so:

```bash
>>> from sympy.parsing.latex import parse_latex
>>> parse_latex(r"\frac {1 + \sqrt {\a}} {\b}")
(sqrt(a) + 1)/b
```

This may change in the future as the Latex parsing is [experimental](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html#experimental-mathrm-latex-parsing)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `ImportError`, I think you would need to install `antlr4`

- conda installation info [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/antlr)
- pip installation info [here](https://pypi.org/project/antlr4-python3-runtime/)

If you use pip, consider this blog post, from a Python core developer:  https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/